# Getting unexpected error with flow in shared module of monorepo using next js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a simple project with monorepo setup. When i try to use/import a [shared module](https://github.com/VivekNeel/monorepo/blob/master/core/functions/utils.js) inside web next js [project](https://github.com/VivekNeel/monorepo/blob/master/web/pages/index.jsx#L4) am getting the below error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Next.js by default won't compile / transpile modules inside node_modules / out-side of the main folder, therefore you get exception on flow syntax at runtime.

I'm using [next-transpile-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules) in order to transpile specific modules.

```js
// next.config.js

const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['shared-ui', 'other-shared-lib']);

modules.exports = withTM({
  ...regular next config
});
```